# Accidently retracted two solutions, but timer is not running

Tags: timer-jobs, farm-solution, retraction

I've accidently retracted two solutions from the farm in WSS3 but luckily the timer is not running so the jobs did not run. Now when I go to Solution Management I see "Error" for their deployment statuses. I would like to retract the retraction so to speak and cancel the jobs so that when the timer does run, they do not get retracted. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "cancel" method on SPSolution's.

If you still have the solution file(s) you can just add the solution again and re-i stall it. First you should start timer job and finish the retraction, and remove solutions though...

Answer (score 1):

Just try this command in SharePoint Management Shell

**stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs**